# Image classification approach for float outputs

Tags: machine-learning, cnn, image-classification

I have an image input and the model should be able to predict its 15 feature values as output. I am being told that i should use an image classification model to solve this. can somebody suggest me a method to do this or give me insight to a similar problem solution